# How to test an application using WiFi Direct API

Tags: wifi-direct

I'm trying to create an application using the Wi-Fi Direct API. i 'am using the code bellow with 2 class :

1- the class WifiDirect :

---

```
package com.example.wifi_direct;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;

public class WifiDirect extends Activity {


    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //To register the BroadastReceiver
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel =  (Channel) mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); //It was necessary to make a cast (Channel)
        mReceiver = new WiFiBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this, this);


        //To define the filter in the BroadcastReceiver
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

   // unregister the broadcast receiver
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

}
```

2 - the class WiFiBroadcastReceiver:

---

```
package com.example.wifi_direct;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important Wi-Fi p2p events.
 */

public class WiFiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WifiDirect activity;
    //For toast, add also context
    private Context context;

    public WiFiBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, WifiDirect activity, Context context) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();


        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
             int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
             if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.print("ddddddddddddddd");

             } else {
                 System.out.print("ddddvvvvvvvdddd");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is not enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }      

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

i'am beginner in using this API, and i want to know how to test if Wi-Fi is enabled or no..( what should i do in my Activity to see if that works or no ) , thanks in advence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if wifi is on or not by this method

WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){

//wifi is enabled

}

and dont forgot to have permission

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. So, the option is to follow these steps to make your own complete code:

1. **Android Sdk Manager**
2. Download Samples for **Android 4.2.2 (API 17)** (if already installed)
3. Go to C:\android-sdk-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-17\WiFiDirectDemo or where your sdk
    is located

Now, make your demo by copying all the files one by one in eclipse. **You can not import this code** directly because this is not functional code as it doesn't contain **project.properties**.

All the best to newbies....